# How do I create a column down the right-hand side of my site?

Tags: columns

How do I create a column down the right-hand side of my site?

I changed a setting on one of the pages some time ago, and on that page I have the result that I'm looking for:

On this page: http://richardclunan.com/copywriting-critique/ I have a column on the right.

But I've forgotten what setting I changed. For example, on this page: http://richardclunan.com/ there's no column.

I want to create that column on every page.

Comment: Do not mix questions. _Ask Question_ is a singular for a reason. ;) Please edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using the standard Twenty Eleven theme, so all you need to do is go edit the page in question from the admin side, and then if you havent changed the orders of things there, you should have a meta-box with a drop down titled "**Template**". Choose the "**Sidebar Template**" in the drop down and then save your page.